# Four Level Multi-Level Sort Using usort

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I have the following array I need to do a multilevel sort on. I need to sort on room, then safe, then drawer, then shelf.

```
$eritems[] = array(
    'case_name' => $case['case_name'],
    'bag_number' => $check_in['f_bag_number'],
    'room' => $room[$check_in['f_room']],
    'safe' => $safe[$check_in['f_safe']],
    'drawer' => $drawer[$check_in['f_drawer']],
    'shelf' => $shelf[$check_in['f_shelf']]
);
```

Does anyone have a good comparer function for usort? I've only performed single level sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those elements can be compared with `<` and `>`.

```
$sorted_eritems = usort($eritems, function($a, $b)
{
    foreach (array('room', 'safe', 'drawer', 'shelf') as $sort_prop)
    {
        if ($a[$sort_prop] < $b[$sort_prop])
            return -1;
        else if ($a[$sort_prop] > $b[$sort_prop])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much

Comment: If this answered your question, you should accept it.

Comment: Sorry. New to posting here. Answer accepted and again thank you very much.